# What is the difference in an app using FFmpeg directly VS using Ffmpeg commandline?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Is there any difference between using FFmpeg directly VS using Ffmpeg command line in an application?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't: FFmpeg command line is just an app that use the FFmpeg API. Of course when using the app you are limited to what has been implemented (which is surprisingly much, but it isn't as extensive as the API).